# OpenCV on ESP32 Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-nano, signal-processing, opencv

I am implementing a program on Arduino Nano ESP32: the KY-037 microphone is connected to the board and collects five seconds of analog signal. Then, an algorithm is applied to create a 128 x 128 matrix from the five-second signal. Now, I would like to apply the HOGDescriptor function from OpenCV.
Are there any possibilities to do so? How can OpenCV be installed on Arduino?

Comment: I vote to reopen. The question that is marked as duplicate only talks about the classic AVR based Arduinos. OpenCV on an ESP32 is possible, though in a reduced form. One seems to need the ESP32-DOWDQ6 chip for it. A quick search gave me [this github project with OpenCV for ESP32 cross-compiled](https://github.com/joachimBurket/esp32-opencv) and [this article on hackaday and the associated video](https://hackaday.com/2022/05/19/opencv-running-on-tiny-microcontroller/) about the ESP32-CAM.

Comment: @chrisl I seen that library. Another way to solve this limitation is to run the arduino code until before the OpenCV library, which will run on a Python script on PC. Not perfect but I will try